# error in date items, daylight Saving

Tags: datetime, xpages

Summer dates in an input control which are before 1981 are recalculated (I think with daylight saving time).

e.g. 
e.g. I enter 27.8.1960 - after a save I got 26.8.1960, (after the next save 25.8.1960 and so on)
but 27.8.2010 - after a save it stayed the same: 27.8.2010

"Winter dates": 27.4.1960 - after a save it stayed the same: 27.4.1960

looks like an ugly bug. how can I supress this "calculation"?

(date format is Europeen, I live in Germany. 27.8.1960 is August 27, 1960)

thanks for any help, Uwe

```
<xp:inputText value="#{Auftrag.MF_GebDatum}" id="mF_GebDatum1" style="width:255px">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Is the document field saved as *DateTime* including the correct Timezone information?

Comment: Hi Sven, it is saved as DateTime: 
26.08.1960 00:00:00 CEDT
27.08.2010 00:00:00 CEDT
(both viewed in the notes client)

Comment: Hmm... A daylight saving time problem??? The Time is stored as CEDT and the server "corrects" it to CET (-1 Hour). This would result in 25.08.1960 23:00:00 CET, will then saved as 25.08.1960 00:00:00 CEDT and so on...

Comment: To fix this you could adjust the Time to 12:00:00. Then the correcting of the timezone wouldn't affect the Date itself.

Comment: But why does the server corrects "summer dates" before 1981, and lets the dates since 1981 as they are? 
... the 12:00 "workaround: Well - I have quite a lot date fields in that form, and I hoped there is an easier (and better) way than to script a ssjs onsubmit which gives all those dates a 12:00

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are fighting with is that Domino stores a datetime value with the daylight saving information which does not exists for the dates you are entering. The information for the timezone to use comes from the current user locale and / or the server.

Your date is stored in a field with the timezone it was *entered* (+2h GMT)

```
26.08.1960 00:00:00 CEDT
```

Domino interprets the stored value as it is, without adjusting it

```
var ndt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("26.08.1960 00:00:00 CEDT");
ndt.getGMTTime()
```

returns the correct datetime value, adjusted by 2 hours for GMT

```
25.08.60 22:00:00 GMT
```

While converted back to Java, it is interpreted "correctly" that there was never a daylight saving time in 1960, that's why it will be adjusted only by 1 hour:

```
var ndt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("26.08.1960 00:00:00 CEDT");
ndt.toJavaDate().toLocaleString()
```

will result in "25.08.1960 23:00:00" if you are in the CEDT timezone.

Currently the only idea I have for an easy workaround is to kill the Timezone information in the DateTime field. To do this you can use this SSJS script:

```
<xp:this.querySaveDocument>
   <![CDATA[#{javascript:
      var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument( true );
      var items:java.util.Vector = doc.getItems();
      var item:NotesItem;
      var ndt:NotesDateTime;
      var dt:java.util.Date;

      for( var i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
         item = items.get(i);
         if( item.getType() === 1024 ){
            ndt = item.getValueDateTimeArray().get(0);  
            ndt = session.createDateTime( ndt.getDateOnly());
            item.setDateTimeValue( ndt );
            ndt.recycle();
         }
         item.recycle();
      }
   }]]>
</xp:this.querySaveDocument>
```

Comment: Hi Sven, 
thanks for your answer - I needed some time to verify it (because of a very good project management in my company ;-)  -
Your workaround doesn't solve the problem, I think the reason is that then var ndt already has the wrong date, so an ...ndt.getDateOnly() gives me the -1 day-date. 

Uwe