# XPages date only fieldonly

Tags: xpages

Is it possible to create a date only field in XPages? I have tried the following in the querySaveDocument event but the field still ends up with a time portion of 00:00:00

```
var notesDoc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument();
var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(@Today());
dt.setAnyTime();
notesDoc.replaceItemValue("MyDateField", dt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code by Sven:

```
ndt = session.createDateTime(ndt.getDateOnly());
item.setDateTimeValue(ndt);
```

[error in date items, daylight Saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275752/error-in-date-items-daylight-saving)

**Update:**

I had to do the same thing and found out that it's working this way in Java agent in 8.5.2FP3:

```
DateTime dt = session.createDateTime(new java.util.Date());
dt.setAnyTime();
doc.appendItemValue("DT", dt);
```

Comment: This post on notes.net has a similar answer for SSJS http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllThreadedWeb/197990867295e358852576af0083d305?OpenDocument

Answer (score 3):

It is not completely clear what you are trying achieve.

You can put an EditBox component on your XPage, then go to the "Data" tab. From there you can change the formatting from String to Date. More options should appear on how to format the date in the field. It will handle passing the date to the back end document.

[image: Data Properties Tab]

If it is you want to write directly to the back end document, then here is a page listing samples on working with NotesDateTime.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/NotesDateTime_sample_JavaScript_code_for_XPages

Comment: I'm creating an XPages ui for an existing Notes client app. In the client a NotesDateTime field is created with only a date component - no time component is present. I'm trying to replicate this on the XPage, so that I don't have to revisit the views, etc that are used in the Notes client to display this field.

Comment: That should do what you want then. Just set to Custom date.