# XPages - save date only in Date field

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I'm using an Edit Box control to display a date field. When the XPage is saved, I would like to save the date only (now both date and time are being saved). Is there any way of doing this?

Here is my code:

```
<xp:inputText id="dateReparatur" value="#{document1.dateReparatur}">
<xp:this.converter>
<xp:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="long">
</xp:convertDateTime>
</xp:this.converter>
<xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
</xp:inputText></xp:td>
```

UPDATE: I have now implemented the following code:

```
var dt = currentDocument.getItemValueDateTime("dateReparatur");
var dateonly = dt.getDateOnly();
currentDocument.replaceItemValue("dateReparatur",dateonly);
```

This gives me the date only, however in Notes the field type is now text rather than Date/Time, which is what I was hoping for.

Comment: You may need to do this in your converter or querySaveDocument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439726/xpages-date-only-fieldonly/14440439#14440439

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
    <xp:this.postSaveDocument><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var dt:DateTime = document1.getItemValueDateTime("dateReparatur");
        dt.setAnyTime();
        currentDocument.getDocument(true).replaceItemValue("dateReparatur", dt); 
        currentDocument.getDocument(true).save()
    }]]></xp:this.postSaveDocument>
```

[image]

It does work at `postSaveDocument` event only. If you put the same code into `querySaveDocument` event (without document save() line of course) the date field gets polluted with time after event during saving.

An **alternative** is to execute `computeWithForm` at `querySaveDocument` event:

```
<xp:this.querySaveDocument><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    document1.getDocument(true).computeWithForm(true, true)
}]]></xp:this.querySaveDocument>
```

You'd have to add an `Input Translation` formula to date field(s) in your form:

```
@Date(@ThisValue)
```

`computeWithForm` has a poor performance and causes sometimes side effects on field values though but might be a good solution especially if you have a lot of such date-only-fields.

Answer (score 1):

`getDateOnly()` returns a string. Try this:

```
dt.setAnyTime();
currentDocument.replaceItemValue("dateReparatur", dt);
```

Or you may have to get the `Document`:

```
currentDocument.getDocument(true).replaceItemValue("dateReparatur", dt);
```

Comment: I tried this but the "dateReparatur" field in notes is empty.

Comment: Did you try with an item name that is not bound to any field on XPage? That's a good way to chek that it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I decided to go with Knut's solution as it worked well.