# xpages current time and username when doc. is created in javascript

Tags: javascript, xpages

I want to display the time when a document is created via xpages. In clasic lotus notes I'd use computed when composed field.

A computed field is displaying the current date:

```
session.createDateTime("Today")
```

How can I display the current time ( when I compose a document / an xpage ) ?

I tried something like this in a computed field:

```
var ndt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today");
ndt.toJavaDate().toLocaleString()
```

but it displays the date too and i think every time I opened the doc. the date changes.

For displaying the username, I tried adding a computed label:

```
    if (currentDocument.isNewNote())
{return @Name("[CN]", session.getEffectiveUserName());
}
```

But, if I re-open the document later, of course the label value is empty, I should add in the `else` case something like `@ThisValue` from Lotus Notes.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439726/xpages-date-only-fieldonly)

Comment: I tried with .getTimeOnly() but I get an error

Comment: Could you use `doc.appendItemValue("yourElement", ndt);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply a datetime converter to your control and set it to show time only.

*Update:*

Just read your last remark regarding the changing of values. Maybe you are mistaking the role of a Computedfield control in xpages with the one a computed field has within a Notes Form: in xpages the control is like a "computed for Display" field as it doesn't store values in a doc, it just displays them. In your case you might want to use a combination of a beforePageload event where you write the current date time value to the Notes field, if the datasource isNew(). Your computed field then is showing the value stored before.

*Update #2:*

In case you just wanted to display the time of day when the doc was first created you of course don't need to calculate and store that value in your documents. Instead just use the computedField mentioned above, then apply a ssjs version of `@Created` to it. Finally apply the beforementioned Datetime converter to the control.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually, nKn, this is generally considered the best practice approach for implementing what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @nkn, i usually go into more, maybe even too much detail with my answers. i had to keep it short this time as i wrote it using a mobile phone. just cause i kept the answer short, it wasnt meant to be criticism but to help solve the problem.

Comment: @Lothar Thanks for the info, actually i was looking for a computed for display field similar to classic Notes

Comment: Then i probably got it slightly wrong. Is it that you just want to show the time of day when qthe doc was first created? See update 2 to my answer, then

Comment: Thank you for your tips! Btw, is there any chance I could use only labels , and not any computed field ?

Comment: of course you can; just use the same SSJS code yuo're using for your computedField in a label control's computed value property