# Saving date with Java : This field is not a valid date

Tags: java, date, xpages

On an xpage I have an inputtext control:

```
<xp:inputText
                value="#{employeeBean.employee.dateOfEmployment}">
                <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today");
dt.adjustMonth(-6);
return dt.getDateOnly();}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>

                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
                </xp:this.converter>
            </xp:inputText>
```

The value can be e.g.: 2016-10-06

When I want to save my object I get the following message for this field:

This field is not a valid date

Can anybody tell me what can be the cause of this and how I should correct my code?

Comment: This error message occurs if inputText's value property is undefined. Make sure `employeeBean`, `employeeBean.getEmployee()` and `employeeBean.getEmployee().setDateOfEmployment(NotesDateTime)` are available

Comment: Hello Knut, are you saying that I should change the type for the date property from Date to NotesDate time in my Employee class?

Comment: I have tried the following: NotesContext nct = NotesContext.getCurrent();
   Session session = nct.getCurrentSession();
   doc.replaceItemValue("since", session.createDateTime( employee.getDateOfEmployment()) ); Which works when the xp:inputText control uses a format like "Oct 6, 2015". If I change the format to "2015/10/06" this will fail. This last format is the format that I would like to use since I expect users are more custom to work with this format.

Comment: I applied a convertor to the inputText control, this seems to do the job just fine: <xp:this.converter>
     <xp:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDateOnly()` function returns the date part of the `NotesDateTime` as a string, but for an `xp:inputText` that needs to store a date you need to work with a `java.util.Date`. Try this format:

```
@Adjust( @Now(), 0, -6, 0, 0, 0,0);
```

You will probably notice that the format of the returned date is different in the input field, but that's format the input control/ server will interpret as a date. If you need a different format, you can always change the converter into something like this:

```
<xp:this.converter>
         <xp:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"></xp:convertDateTime>
</xp:this.converter>
```

Comment: Hello Mark, that convertor works just fine. Thank you for the help. But is it possible to store the date without the time stamp? If I would save the document via a Notes form then I have the plain date value saved only. Frankly I am not interested at what specific hour a person is employed :-)

Comment: Since you're already using a bean, you could handle that in the backend. `dateOfEmployment` is probably already a Date. When storing it in a document as a `NotesDateTime`, you could call `setAnyTime()` on the `NotesDateTime` before storing it in the field.

Comment: Further to Mark's answer, this is also covered in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439726/xpages-date-only-fieldonly

Comment: If you're in control of the Java class, `java.sql.Date` only contains the date portion, without a time. If you're setting it via API, then with the latest release of ODA, you can pass a `java.sql.Date` to `replaceItemValue()`, and ODA will auto-box it so that it stores as date only.